# Is it good approach to "pass" function template as generic-variadic lambda return statement?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

I was having fun with attempts to pass function template as `template template` argument. Of course C++ doesn't allow passing function templates this way. But I came up with simple hax:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PASS_TEMPLATE(name) [](auto&... args){return name(args...);}

template <typename T, typename S>
void function_template(T t, S s) {std::cout << t << ' ' << s << std::endl;}

template <typename Hax, typename T, typename S>
auto test(Hax hax, T t, S s)
{
    return hax(t, s);
}

int main()
{
    test(PASS_TEMPLATE(function_template), 1, 1.5);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0164a87920171e07)

The question is:

- Is this viable approach? (Is it safe? No corner cases?)
- Is it universal, or are there cases that will cause compilation to fail?
- Are there other alternatives to achieve this? (I know some people don't like macros)

I was testing this only on GCC 6.1.0 (I really hope it's not GCC extension or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using perfect forwarding, but aside from that it's a perfectly viable (and probably the only aside from manually typing it all) approach to the problem.

So, that would be:

```
#define PASS_TEMPLATE(name) [](auto&&... args){return name(decltype(args)(args)...);}
```

[GCC was broken with generic stateless lambdas](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c34e5999995b4e92), so you had to add at least minimal state like `[dummy=nullptr]` or something like that. Luckily they fixed it.

Comment: Having the macro (which I call `BIND_FREEFUNC`) makes passing arbitrary non-member functions as callbacks trivial, without involving function pointers. This can be quite useful.

Comment: As a bonus, since the lambda isn't capturing anything, it can be converted to a function pointer, so it's pretty flexible for working with different APIs.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::forward`?

Comment: Because it doesn't actually add anything there but wordiness and an admittedly irrelevant extra-dependency.

Answer (score 4):

It is fine, except you would probably want to enable perfect forwarding:

```
#define PASS_TEMPLATE(name) [](auto&&... args){return name(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);}
```

Comment: Won't this prevent arguments to be modified by reference? At least coliru says so: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c34e5999995b4e92.

Comment: @BlackMoses Looks like it should work to me... though it doesn't.

Comment: That doesn't work because GCC is buggy. [Clang works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daafcde8d47b152a), as expected.

Comment: One possible GCC workaround is to use a captureful lambda, e.g. `[dummy=1]`.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the workaround, though I lament the loss of statelessness.

Comment: @Deduplicator The GCC bug is triggered by the conversion function template to function pointer, so...hard to not lose it.