# Is it possible to pass variable template to function through lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, variable-templates

As I know how to [pass template function as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933137/is-it-good-approach-to-pass-function-template-as-generic-variadic-lambda-retur), I'm now struggling to pass variable template in a similar manner.

Here is minimal example of what I tried:

```
#define PASS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATE(name) [dummy=nullptr](auto&&...args) \
                                                    {return name<decltype(args)...>;}

//testing
template <typename T>
bool value = std::is_fundamental<T>::value;

template <typename Hax>
void print_bool(Hax h)
{
    std::cout << h(int{}) << std::endl; // no error, wrong output
    //std::cout << h(int{}, float{}) << std::endl; // error, good
}

int main()
{
    print_bool(PASS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATE(value)); //prints 0 instead of 1
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/effebcf36e120e4b)

If it compiles, then why the output is wrong?

Comment: Is a reference good enough?

Comment: @lorro Oh silly me, forgot to do the decaying! But on other hand that would destroy reference/pointer checking... It should be possible to check this case too: `int b; int& ref = a; h(ref); //type is int&`

Comment: You will get the expected results with 
`#define PASS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATE(name) [dummy=nullptr](auto&&args)
 {
  return name<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(args)>::type>;
 }`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, but on the other hand if `std::is_rvalue_reference` was applied instead, wouldn't it break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T; constexpr tag_t(){}};
template<class Tag>using tagged_type=typename Tag::type;
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

These help pass types as values and unpack them.

```
#define PASS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATE(name) [](auto...args) \
                                                {return name<tagged_type<decltype(args)>...>;}
```

Inside `print_bool` you do:

```
std::cout << h(tag<int>) << std::endl;
```

Not sure why you do the `dummy=nullptr` thing.

`tag` as a template can carry types unmolested.

Comment: `dummy` is due to GCC bug with non-capturing lambda (check out the accepted answer from link I posted in the question). Btw, great solution.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is that `decltype` deduces the arguments as an `rvalue` reference (`int&&`) because your lambda uses *forwarding references* to accept the arguments.
 [`std::is_fundamental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental) will work well with a *bare* type.

For your specific snippet, the correct solution is to [remove the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

```
#define PASS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATE(name) \
    [dummy=nullptr](auto&&...args){return name<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(args)>...>;}
```

Now it works. :-) See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e47324d37255efa)

---

A slightly more or better generic way will be to additionally [remove cv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) qualifiers. In the end, you may want to use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

```
#define PASS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATE(name) [dummy=nullptr](auto&&...args) \
{return name<std::decay_t<decltype(args)>...>;}
```